# If possible, write each of the vectors X_1, X_2 and X_3 as a linear combination of vectors in T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let S={X_1,X_2,X_3} be a linearly independent a set of vectors in R^3 and T={Y_1,Y_2,Y_3} be a set of vectors in R^3, where Y_1=X_1+〖2X〗_2-2X_3, Y_2=-X_1-X_2+3X_3 and Y_3=-2X_1-〖3X〗_2+4X_3.

```
If possible, write each of the vectors X_1, X_2 and X_3 as a linear combination of vectors in T.
```

After reducing the matrix, i get all zeros.
I would appreciate some help please
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**: Write the vectors as column vectors. Then you have:
$$
(X_1,X_2,X_3)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 &-1&-2\\2&-1&-3\\-2&3&4\end{pmatrix}=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3).
$$
Let $A$ be the second matrix on the RHS above. You can check $\det(A)=-1$ so $A$ is invertible so, yes, you can  definitely write $X_1,X_2$, and $X_3$ as linear combinations of vectors in $T$. It remains to solve for nine numbers:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 &-1&-2\\2&-1&-3\\-2&3&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_1 &b_2&b_3\\b_4&b_5&b_6\\b_7&b_8&b_9\end{pmatrix}=I_3.
$$
Once you do that, then, for example, $X_1=b_1Y_1+b_4Y_2+b_7Y_3$. To get the $b_\ldots$, use the rule of matrix multiplication to obtain a 3-equation system for $\{b_1,b_4,b_7\}$, another 3-equation system for $\{b_2,b_5,b_8\}$, etc.